# C# COM server and client example

Tags: c#, com

I have COM server with events implemented in C# and don't know how to write a C# client which hooks to events. I found several articles which describe how to do C# server and C++ clients but none (or I'm blind :-P ) which describe how to do the C# client using events. I'm able to connect to the COM server object but have no idea how to hook to the events.

Note I have two applications - one contains the C# COM server and another application which contains the C# client. The server is implemented as follows:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("08214B02-512D-4785-9176-C4B4324FC340")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IMyServer
{
    bool Play(string sFile);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("141CAAEA-63CE-422E-BF00-BAF4DBEEA77A")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IMyServerEvents
{
    [DispId(1)]
    event OnPlayFinishedHandler OnPlayFinished;
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("MyApp.MyServer")]
[Guid("D184855D-E425-46A6-9171-34C828353778")]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IMyServerEvents))]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MyServer : IMyServer, IDisposable
{
    public MyServer()
    {
    }

    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void OnPlayFinishedHandler();
    public event OnPlayFinishedHandler OnPlayFinished;

    public bool Play(string sFile)
    {
        if (OnPlayFinished != null)
            OnPlayFinished();

        return true;
    }
}
```

and now the client, I'm obtaining the COM server object via Running Object Table (not important I think here how).

```
IMyServer oServer = GetServer();

// TODO: Connect to OnPlayFinised event

oServer.Play("C://File.txt");
```

I tried to cast oServer to IMyServerEvents but it is not allowed.

Comment: oServer.Play("C:/File.txt"); is fine

Comment: There is no point whatsoever in using COM when both the server and the client are written in C#.  The IDE will refuse to let you add a COM reference to the server, you must add a normal assembly reference.  Using the ROT is just a hack around that restriction, it is not a practical one.  Impossible to guess why you are doing this, just don't do it.

Comment: This was also my understanding but I'm not sure how to implement my case then. I have two running applications and application "A" should control the second application "B". Is it possible to obtain an object reference (I'm a C++ guy - so I still use pointer :-) ) from the B application and call methods from A ?

Answer (score 1):

As Hans said, you cannot add a COM reference if it's a .NET assembly.  You have to add it as a normal assembly reference.  Have you seen this MSDN example of implementing a C# COM server with events:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Following from that MSDN example, you would then add that C# assembly as a reference in your C# client app.  To hook into the events that the COM server raises, you'd write the event handler and then subscribe to the event.  This sample code refers to the above MSDN example.

```
public void ClickEventHandler(int x, int y)
{
    // The "Click" event was raised on the COM server, handle the event here
}

EventSource.Button myButton = new EventSource.Button();
myButton.Click += new EventSource.ClickDelegate(ClickEventHandler); // subscribe to the event
```